# How to send a List<HashMap<String,String>> list to another activity

Tags: android, list, hashmap

I was trying to send  List> list to another activity. I tried many ways but couldn't. Please help!

Comment: Try sending it as an array

Comment: I tried it but couldn't make it.

Comment: if your list is an arraylist, it is serializable

Comment: sorry its not an arraylist

Comment: What does your data represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Intent`

```
hashMap.put("key", "value");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, otherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mapkey", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

EDIT:

For fatching the value in otherActivity

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("mapkey"); 
    intent.getSerializableExtra("mapkey");
```

EDIT (Convert it back to List) try sth like:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
List<String> hashMap = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
```

Happy coding!

Comment: How will you receive this in the second activity?

Comment: but now we have a hashmap, how to convert it as a list?

Comment: List<HashMap<String,String>> list

Comment: its not working. for your info its giving an error "The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<HashMap<String,String>>)"

Comment: could you please try, `List<HashMap<String>> hashMap = (List<HashMap<String>)` else you could try with string,boolean.. ill test it

Comment: once more to try `HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("mapkey");`

Comment: I think the receiving intent value should be a HashMap